# Is there a way of creating a XML instance document from a given XSD schema in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, xml-generation

Given a valid XSD schema file is there a way to automatically generate an instance XML document from it in Python? I am looking for a very simple way to do that (without any extensive configuration capabilities). I can use `lxml.etree` to later change the data in the document (be it a file or a string residing in the memory).

There are plenty of online tools ([xsd2xml.com](http://xsd2xml.com/) for example) that support this. When it comes to entries that offer a specific set of values (like `xs:enumeration`) many of those tools blindly pick the first valid choice, which (in my case) is perfectly fine.